# There are 2 listviews in an activity, when I click on item in the second listview the item should be added to first listview

Tags: android, listview, onitemclick

The problem is that each time I click on item it is replacing the item that was added early, so the first listview has only the last added item. Here is my code:

```
lvUsersList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            final Contacts contact = (Contacts) adapter.getItem(position);
            final RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
            params.add("member", contact.getId());
            params.add("id", gcId);
            AsyncHttpClient asyncClient = new AsyncHttpClient();
            asyncClient.addHeader("User", userId);
            asyncClient.post("http://prev.gio.uz/addGroupChatMember", params, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {
                    pb.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                    String json = new String(responseBody);
                    try {
                        JSONObject object = new JSONObject(json);
                        JSONObject jsonObject = object.getJSONArray("data").getJSONObject(0);
                        Log.i("myLogs", "gc member added successfully");
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Group member added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    List<AddedUsers> addedUsersList = new ArrayList<AddedUsers>();
                    AddedUsers au = new AddedUsers();
                    au.setId(contact.getId());
                    au.setFullName(contact.getFullName());
                    addedUsersList.add(au);
```

The code is ugly as ****, hope you understand, I'll explain more if needed

Comment: every time when you click on item it will create new object of   AddedUsers au = new AddedUsers(); so every time its a new list on every click

Comment: @Yusuf Abdullaev: u r creating new addedUserList everytime u click on item in 2nd ListView. this line List<AddedUsers> addedUsersList = new ArrayList<AddedUsers>(); instead declare addedUsersList as class member and define it inside onCreate().

Comment: Refresh your both adapters after added to another listView

Comment: @kevz thanx mate it's working, I'm feeling stupid now :)

Comment: @Yusuf Abdullaev: Dude its okay. Keep calm n code :)